# My setInterval is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I do not know why it does not work?
Can you help me please?

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {
  d = new Date();
  utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
  nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
  return nd.toLocaleString();
}

var Paris =setInterval( function() { calcTime('gmt', '+1'); }, 500 );
```

I do not get the value of calcTime in the Paris variable

Comment: What do you expect? What is not working?

Comment: This is how it works  : var Chipre = calcTime('gmt', '+2');         but if I do set intervall it does not work

Comment: People, don't be so harsh on a new member of SO. There was code and it was obvious what he wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) returns an interval pointer, not the value of the function.

You likely want this instead

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {
  var d = new Date();
  var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
  var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
  return nd.toLocaleString();
}
var parisTId =setInterval( function() { 
  document.getElementById("paris").innerHTML=calcTime('gmt', '+1'); 
}, 500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to get the current time in a place with a particular offset in hours (presumably decimal hours since not all timezone offsets are full hours). You can do that fairly simply using:

```
// Offset is per javascript timezone offset, i.e. minutes to subtract
// from UTC to get local time, so for a place that is UTC+01:00 use -60
function calcTime(offset) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset() - offset);
  return d;
}
```

Note that using *toLocaleString* will report the timezone of the users current location, not the timezone that the date has been adjusted for, so you might want to build your own string that has the correct offset (say based on ISO 8601).